# Azure SQL database is not updating with data

Tags: sql, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created a nodejs azure web app and it is running perfectly fine,
Now I want to get my post data to azure MS SQL DB, I have created a code for that, however sql db is not updating with POST data, can anyone help me with this.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sql = require('mssql');
var port = 8080;
var app = express();`enter code here`
var path = require('path');


//CORS Middleware
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin,X-Requested-With,contentType,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization");
    next();
});


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));




//setup database connection
var dbconfig = {
    user:"username",
    password:"password",
    server : "server_name",
    database: "db_name"  
};


// ConnectionPool


//connect to the database 
var executeQuery = function(res,query){
    sql.connect(dbconfig,function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("there is a database connection error -> "+err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            // create request object
            var request = new sql.Request();
            // query to the database
            request.query(query,function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error while querying database -> "+err);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else{
                    res.send(result);
                    sql.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}



app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Hello World',
        showTitle:true,
        people: ['John', 'Steve', 'Jose']
    });
});



app.get('/index', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
    res.render('contact');
});




app.post('/my_user', function(req, res){
    //return res.send(req.body);

    console.log(req.body.email + ' and ' + req.body.mobile);

    var parameters = [
            { name: 'email', sqltype: sql.NVarChar, value: req.body.email},
            { name: 'mobile', sqltype: sql.NInt, value: req.body.mobile},
            { name: 'msg', sqltype: sql.NVarChar,  value: req.body.msg},
     ];

    var query = "insert into forMyCV values(@email, @mobile, @msg);";
        executeQuery (res, query, parameters);

    return res.redirect('/');   
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started on port '+port);
```

can anyone help me with this explain this to me. why this is happening

Comment: No errors? Are you certain the insert code is running? Are you certain the db youre looking in and the db the server is inserting in, are the same db?

Comment: @CaiusJard, yes it is not showing any errors if I created a code only to execute CRUD operation and then I ran it via  'node sql-crud.js', it will execute the code and update the sql table,
I want to update my table when user hit the 'submit' button.
In this code when an user hit the submit button it is not updating the db table

Comment: So the problem is the submit is not invoking the db query? (It's kinda nothing to do with SQL, db, etc... and the question has the wrong tags)

Comment: @CaiusJard, maybe. I don't know, how do I verify it?

Comment: I thought you had verified it, with your comment above, where you basically say "if I run the code directly it works, but if I click the submit button it doesn't"

Comment: @CaiusJard, I meant by that it is above code is running inside main 'app.js' file, If I created only for js file that does CRUD operations only. 
(ex - in my crud.js file if I added "insert into fortable values('test@gmail.com', 67899876, 'testing');")
then ran --> node crud.js
that data is updated in th DB

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there are two issues in your code after I had test it.

1. According to the tab `Connection strings` of your Azure SQL Database on Azure portal as the figure below, there is a required parameter `encrypt=true` in the connection string like for JDBC and others, too.

   [image]

   So the correct `config` for Azure SQL Database using `mssql` should be as below.

   ```
   const config = {
       user: '<your username>@<your sql server name>',
       password: '<your password>',
       server: '<your sql server name>.database.windows.net', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
       database: '<your database name>',

       options: {
           encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
       }
   }
   ```

   The required `options: {encrypt: true}` property can not be ignored. Otherwise, it will cause the error.

   ```
   there is a database connection error -> ConnectionError: Server requires encryption, set 'encrypt' config option to true.
   (node:665784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: res is not defined
   at D:\projects\node\express-demo\mssql-query-demo.js:43:13
   at _poolCreate.then.catch.err (D:\projects\node\express-demo\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:287:7)
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
   (node:665784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
   (node:665784) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
   ```
2. the `executeQuery` function is defined with two parameters `res` and `query`, but it be used with three parameters `executeQuery (res, query, parameters);` in the callback `function(req, res)` of `app.post('/my_user')`. It will not cause any error and just ignore the nonmatched last parameter `parameters`.

Hope it helps.

---

Update: Redefine the executeQuery function as below.

```
var executeQuery = function(res,query, parameters){
    sql.connect(dbconfig,function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("there is a database connection error -> "+err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            // create request object
            var request = new sql.Request();
            // query to the database
            parameters.map(item => {
                request.input(item.name, item.sqltype, item.value);
            })
            request.query(query,function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error while querying database -> "+err);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else{
                    res.send(result);
                    sql.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, How do I send post parameters with this code

Comment: @RandeerLalangaran I updated the code for function `executeQuery`.